# Как указать модель в кастомной команде django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Добавил кастомную команду для django. Как сделать так, что бы я мог указать название модели которую нужно импортировать?

```
python manage.py importcsv data/csf_file.csv Modelname True
```

К примеру при вызове такой команды внутри должна импортироваться модель **Modelname**
Код ниже.

```
import csv

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError

import recipes.models as models


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Import data from csv file'

    def print_error(self, error, row, print_error):
        if print_error:
            print('Error:', error.args, '\nRow ID:', row.get('id'))

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('file_path', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('model', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('print_errors', type=bool)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        file_path = options['file_path']
        print_errors = options['print_errors']
        model = options['model']
        with open(file_path, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
            total_count = 0
            successfull = 0
            for row in csv_reader:
                total_count += 1
                try:
                    models.model.objects.get_or_create(**row)
                    successfull += 1
                except IntegrityError as error:
                    self.print_error(error, row, print_errors)
                except ValueError as error:
                    self.print_error(error, row, print_errors)
            errors = total_count - successfull
            print('Model: {}\nSuccessfull: {}; errors: {}'.format(
                models.model.__name__, successfull, errors
            ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не правильно

```
try:
    models.model.objects.get_or_create(**row)
```

Правильно

```
try:
    getattr(models,model).get_or_create(**row)
 ....
except AttributeError as error::
    print('Модели нет')
    break
```

Comment: Что-то не получается. AttributeError: module 'recipes.models' has no attribute 'getattr'

Comment: туплю, сейчас исправлю)